# replacement for vb6 resume next

Tags: vb.net

I have following code and I need to replace On Error GoTowith try catch block. but the problem i am finding in the Resume Next statement. how to handle resume next in try catch block?

```
Private Function Add()
    'On Error GoTo PreXmtErr
    bSkipError = True
    Divide(hRequestBlock, "@VIEW-QUALIFIER", 0, sWorkBuffer)
    bSkipError = False

    bSkipError = True
    subtract(hRequestBlock, "INBOUND-@VIEW-ID", 0, sWorkBuffer)
    bSkipError = False

PreXmtErr:             
    If bSkipError = True Then
       bSkipSetItem = True
       Resume Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just move the second code block in the Catch clause, no need for the bSkipError variable anymore.

Comment: `Resume Next` is generally bad anyway.  If you don't know exactly what happened then how can you assume that it's safe to carry on from the next statement? Many times it will be OK but there are times that it won't and those times could result in data loss or corruption. There's just no way to know. In VB.NET, you should ONLY catch SPECIFIC exceptions that you understand the consequences of.  Any unexpected exceptions should be the responsibility of a global exception handler that exits or restarts the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Functions need a datatype
Private Function Add() As Double
    Dim ReturnValue As Double
    Try
        Divide(hRequestBlock, "@VIEW-QUALIFIER", 0, sWorkBuffer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Divide failed") 'can delete this line but empty catches just swallow errors
    End Try
    Try
        subtract(hRequestBlock, "INBOUND-@VIEW-ID", 0, sWorkBuffer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("subtract failed") 'can delete this line but empty catches just swallow errors
    End Try
    bSkipSetItem = True
    'Functions no longer use FunctionName = to return
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.